# Windows 10 Product Key Expiration

Tags: windows, windows-10, product-key

Here's what my Windows 10 32-bit Enterprise Edition is showing via slmgr/xps method of activation check :

[image: http://prntscr.com/8ce0mv]

What should i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. [You activated via KMS, which is only valid for 180 days](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831612.aspx) and have to repeated again if that 180days are over.